# White Screen Hang Mac Pro

Tags: startup, screen, performance

Reading related posts it seems I have a blend of other's issues.  But the final blow was plugging in a nextbook tablet to download some pdf files, and THEN I booted the old Mac Pro 2008 with Yosemite 10.10.3 or 4, can't recall exactly now since I can't check it.  I 'assume' having the tablet plugged in on boot confused the boot up sequence?

I've tried every startup key configuration in the official Apple list, except trying the few 'over the internet' options i.e. 'Option-D: Apple Hardware Test/Apple Diagnostics over the internet,' 'Command-Option-B Start up from OS X Recovery over the internet,' because my hardwired modem is on the computer I'm using to get help.  I'll power this down and try it now, but if that doesn't work, which isn't likely, it's still in White Screen Hang.  It was also black screen crashing before this and restarting over and over, intermittently... if that may be contributing to this issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Already tried NVRAM reset?

I've been surprised by how many problems this "fixes":
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

> Turn on your Mac.
>
> Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys immediately after you hear the startup sound.
>
> Hold these keys until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for a second time.
>
> Release the keys.

Comment: Thank you, Jaime Santa Cruz.  Yes, I did, but I think I did it incorrectly re: the holding and sounds.  I'll be able to try this again Wednesday, and I'll RSVP.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Jaime Santa Cruz:  I was able to get to this tonight and unfortunately it didn't work.  I did it twice, just to make sure, and the 2nd time, the HD started whirring way fast/loud, so I power button powered down before it blew.  It had done this for me a couple+ times before when I was trying different things.  So, I'm still getting the Apple logo, progress bar goes about 1/4 to 1/3 across, then stops, white screen, with the pointer up in the upper left corner.  Any idea why plugging in a nextbook tablet would do that?  Seller told me I could download pdf files from my Mac.  ?  Thanks.

Comment: gah, formatting fail....let's try that again...

Had to go find the site again, but I thought I remembered there being offline diagnostics options:
(from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255 )


**Shift**  _Start up in Safe Mode._                        
**D**  _Start up to either Apple Hardware Test or Apple Diagnostics, depending on which Mac you're using._                 
**Command-R**  _Start up from OS X Recovery._ (this one may not help much, but I think I remember there being some "repair" option in there.

Comment: Jaime Santa Cruz:  Thank you.  I'll try those again.  After I tried many, I even printed out the 'Startup key combinations for Mac' official list from Apple Support, and tried them all again, except the ones that required the internet connection, which I'm using now to get help from AD/you.  I ended up with white screen hang, but I will try the above again per your suggestion.  Then,I'll have to change internet connection and try the  Option-D Startup AHT or AD over the internet... BUT I won't know what to do once I get there unless there are instructions.  Thanks!

Comment: Where did my comment go?  Trying again:  Thanks.  That's the list of official Apple Startup Key Combination for Mac I printed out after trying some I found elsewhere.  Then I went thru the entire list again, except the ones requiring internet connection, which is on this machine, obviously.  I will try the above again, but if I get into the AHT/AD, or even OS X Recovery, I won't know what to do. I'll connect the internet to the MacPro2008 with white screen hang and do the Option-D and Comman-Option-D over the internet and see.  The MP2012 I'm on now is for sale.

Comment: Sorry, my first reply wasn't showing up, now there it is and I can't seem to delete it.

Comment: Shift ended up in another black screen crash.  When it powered up again, I held the D, and it also crashed, then when it came on again, I pressed Command-R and NOW I have 2 different graphics oscillating back and forth, I've had this before but I didn't know what to do.  One looks like it may be a mouse with an arrow pointing UP but I tried and there's no switch on my MightyMouse.  The other's probably a keyboard and I have the metal flat kbd with nothing on the side to switch.  So... I hope you're there now!  I'll let this continue and wait a while to see if you reply.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried all your suggestions and came up with the oscillating graphics but didn't know what to do with them.  I stepped out for a minute and when I came back, it was black screen, no response, but the power light at the button was still on.  Later, I tried the internet startups: Command-Option-R and Option-D with same white screen hang.  Trying the Command-Option-P-R again it kept rebooting over and over to black screen without going into the logo and startup.  In each case the progress bar always goes around 1/4 to 1/3 across, then to white screen.  Thanks.

Comment: Well..I have to say I'm stumped...The tablet should not be able to do that much damage to your install.  Only thing I can think of now is to reinstall OSX, which you probably can do from the 2012 to the 2008, as long as you have an 8GB USB stick and a (Firewire?) cable you can connect to two together with? (You would end up losing anything on the 2008 though)

Comment: Thank you.  You're probably right... unfortunately.  I DO get to the 2 oscillating graphics, one looks like a mouse with an arrow apparently suggesting to push a tab or something in the upward position but there isn't one that I can see, on my mouse.  And the other pic looks like it might represent the side of a slim keyboard with a mark on the side maybe suggesting doing something there, but nothing but the mouse usb plug on the sides of these metal flat keyboards.  So, what am I supposed to do once I see that?  I pressed a few keys but nothing went to next screen, then it black screened. Thx

Comment: I emailed nextbook tech support and also contacted nearest Mac authorized repair over an hour away... may take it there.  BUT if you have input on the 2 oscillating graphics, I can try that first.  Yea or nay so I know whether or not to go elsewhere.  I appreciate your help.  Thank you.

Comment: I think you may better taking it to the Mac repair place, but bring the tablet and have them set it up for you while they're at it.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help.  I took the tablet back.  I hope I don't need it when I take this to repair.  I was thinking of getting a new HD from OWC and putting that in bay 1/boot, format/install OSX, then put this trashed drive in bay 2 and mess with it a bit.  Then, if necessary, take the drive out and take it to repair, IF that will work.  Do you think it will work?  I'm using my OLD Mac Mini for internet since the 2012 sold, and having trouble with 'basic mode' email client, so if you don't hear back, that's why until I get another computer.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Well, having another drive that boots would let get your stuff off the old one so long as the old drive itself hasn't failed, so it's definitely worth a shot. Maybe just wipe the old drive and keep it as a backup after.

Comment: Thank you. I messed with it more and got thru the Option hold again to the choices of startups with the boot USB plugged in. This time, I chose the 'Recovery' disk option and got thru the 'Reinstall OSX' ordeal. Getting thru the setup screens it did get my Desktop back. I'm doing an emergency backup now, just in case, THEN, I'll try powering down and back up again to see if it's going to stay put.  I may be back!  Thanks again for your invaluable help.  Hopefully I can return the gift some day.